# How to use the functional style on my RemoteChunkingManagerStepBuilderFactory?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-stream, spring-integration-dsl, spring-cloud-function, spring-batch-integration

I am implementing Spring Batch-Integration RemoteChunking.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#remote-chunking

I've come across the deprecation of @Input and the documentation says we have to use the functional style.

**How can I use the Consumer** (which is used on the spring cloud stream) in my **Spring Batch Integration Flows?**

```
package pt.bayonne.sensei.RemoteChunking.manager;

import org.aspectj.bridge.Message;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Sinks;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

@Profile("!worker")
@Configuration
public class FunctionalBinders {


    @Bean
    public Sinks.Many<Object> sink() {
        return Sinks.many()
                .replay()
                .latest();
    }


    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<Object>> clientRequests() {
        return () -> sink()
                .asFlux()
                .cache();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<?>> onClientReplies(){
        return message -> {
            //do your stuff
        };
    }
}
```

My JobConfiguration

```
public TaskletStep dispatchStep(){
       return this.remoteChunkingManagerStepBuilderFactory.get("dispatch-step")
                .chunk(10)
                .reader(reader())
                .outputChannel((message, timeout) -> sink.tryEmitNext(message).isSuccess())
                .inputChannel(replies()) //how to use the functional style here?
                .build();

}
```

I know that **it needs a PollableChannel** but my question is **how to use the functional style on my RemoteChunkingManagerStepBuilderFactory?**

Any example would be very appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you use it before with @Input? I am not sure what relation this has to Spring Cloud Stream as you are building a batch app.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky thanks for your reply. Definitely, it has nothing to do with Spring cloud Steam but the reason I asked is the documentation of "@Input" itself says it is "@deprecated as of 3.1 in favor of functional programming model", so i just want to see how i can use the functional style on Spring Batch Integration on RemoteChunkingManagerStepBuilderFactory. I am using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka as message middleware binding.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "functional style". Are you referring to functional bean registration in Spring (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19398)? Using Spring Cloud Function to implement Remote Chunking is a different thing (and I'm not sure if it is practical or even feasible by design, ie using a streaming solution to implement a batch application).

Comment: Hi @MahmoudBenHassine As you can see on the above code snippet I used lambda on outputChannel like  .outputChannel((message, timeout) -> sink.tryEmitNext(message).isSuccess()). My question was if it is possible to use labmda too in the .inputChannel( ). I had to ask here because of the deprecation of "@Input" which i use on SubscribableChannel. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .outputChannel((message, timeout) -> sink.tryEmitNext(message).isSuccess())
> .inputChannel(replies()) //how to use the functional style here?

The method `org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.RemoteChunkingManagerStepBuilder#outputChannel(MessageChannel)` accepts a `org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel` which is a functional interface (See how [it is annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/MessageChannel.html)). Hence you can use a lambda to define the output channel in the builder.

However, `org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.RemoteChunkingManagerStepBuilder#inputChannel(PollableChannel)` accepts a `org.springframework.messaging.PollableChannel` which is *not* a functional interface. That's why it is not possible to use a lambda in here.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now we need to do something else like workaround because the company doesn't allow us to use deprecated things, in our case is "@Output" from Spring Integration Messaging. Our Sonar compains more than any thing :)